# How to open default email client in Android, without sending a message?

Tags: java, android, email, android-intent, kotlin

I'm looking for a way to open default email application on Android, but without using it to send a message. I know I can do this using `mailto://` or intent params, but this automatically opens new message screen. What I want to to archieve, is just opening the app itself.

So far, I have tried

```
override fun startEmailApplication() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

But every time I get

`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.APP_EMAIL] flg=0x10000000 }`

Altrough an email app (AquaMail, Outlook) is installed.

Comment: That't now how you use `CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL). You are supposed to use that with [`makeMainSelectorActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#makeMainSelectorActivity(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). On a recent project, we tried to do what you are seeking (go to the inbox of the user's email app), and we abandoned the effort as being fundamentally unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combinaison a little things.

1. Detect the responding packages for a given Intent:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
   intent.setType("text/plain");
   List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
   boolean canResolve = resolveInfos.size() > 0;
   ```

This will list the available packages to respond to such Intent. Using `queryIntentActivities()` allows me to retrieve `ResolveInfo` which exposes more information about the app.

2. Select the first one and open it using its packageName:

   ```
   if (resolveInfos.size() > 0) {
       startActivity(getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(resolveInfos.get(0).resolvePackageName))
   }
   ```

You also won't have the `ActivityNotFoundException` because we check before hand that something will respond to our `Intent`. Feel free to handle the failing case in a `else`.

Answer (score -2):

You can do the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```